# Jersey 2.25.1 Client Logging Example

Tags: jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using the Jersey 2.25.1 Client and can't get any log output. I've looked at the 2.25.1 documentation - 
https://www.scribd.com/document/350321996/Jersey-Documentation-2-25-1-User-Guide 
- and followed what they described for Client logging -

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_VERBOSITY_CLIENT, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

Is there an addition step that I am missing? The request is working as expected. The application is running on a Glassfish server and using SLF4J. My understanding was that the output would be logged to the server.log.

Comment: Your client application is running on `Glassfish` server and using `SLF4j` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to register a logging Filter

`clientConfig.register(new MyLogFilter());`

You need to create a log filter

```
class MyLogFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyLogFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, requestContext.getEntity().toString()); // you can configure logging level here
    }
}
```